# C# - Binding FormClosing event to cause Form refresh

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling, formclosing

I am having some difficulty getting a form to refresh when another form is closed. This is what I have so far, but it doesn't seem to trigger the refresh. I am very to new to programming, so any assistance is appreciated!

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AddNewCourse ANCform = new AddNewCourse();
    ANCform.FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler(this.ANC_FormClosing);
    ANCform.Show();
}
private void ANC_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    this.Refresh();
}
```

Comment: This never needs any help if you code correctly.  Stop using CreateGraphics(), it is not correct code.

Comment: What is this.Refresh suposed to "refresh"?

Comment: It is refreshing the original Form... The code I have put here is in Form 1. The button opens Form 2. When I close Form 2, I need Form 1 to refresh.

Comment: explain the need to use the refresh in the form 1

Comment: Form one has a gridview showing data from a database. The button opens a new form where a new record can be entered into the database. Once the data is added, the window can be closed. I would like to have the original form with the gridview refreshed so that it immediately shows the new record that was entered.

Comment: this.refresh wont rebind the datasource of a gridview. that could be why you arent getting what you need it to do

Comment: just use the same method you used to populate the grid in the first place, and call that on formclosing. that will update your grid.

Comment: I have used this.Hide() followed by this.Show() and that seems to refresh the gridview, but I just need to work out how to trigger that with the closing of the second form.

Comment: call them in the form closing event?

Comment: @Takarii Perfect! That's exactly what I need. Thankyou. How do I mark your answer correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rebind the datasource of your `DataGridView` in `ANC_FormClosing`

For example, if I were rebinding using a method that fetches data, I might write

```
private void ANC_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridView.DataSource = GetFromDB();
}
```

This refreshes the grid with new data fresh from the DB

Comment: It was placing the original Load commands into the FormClosing event handler, which was the databinding of the gridview to the two database tables. ie:
 private void ANC_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            Refresh();
            this.courseTableAdapter.Fill(this.libraryDBDataSet1.Course);
            this.student_CourseTableAdapter.Fill(this.libraryDBDataSet.Student_Course);
        }

Comment: @DaveOli The reason why invoking `this.Hide()` and `this.Show()` also appears to work is not due to the `Refresh()` method, but because the `Show()` method invokes the `on_load` event.

Comment: Also, I realised in the other form I was using this.Hide instead of this.Close so it wasn't actually triggering the FormClosing

Comment: common mistake, I know i used to make that one in my early days